# Using a custom class in another class? How do I use Point class in a Circle class?

Tags: java, geometry, point

So I believe I have completed my Point class, but now I have to create a Circle class with said Point class.

The variables of the Circle class is x, y and r (x, y are the coordinates of the center point and r is the radius). I'm suppose to 'create' a Point to store x and y, what does this mean? Can I just define a private variable using Point?

How do I create this connection between 2 classes?

Comment: *"I'm suppose to 'create' a Point to store x and y, what does this mean? Can I just define a private variable using Point?"*  That is probably how I would do it, but you should ask whoever set this task.  We cannot answer for them.

Comment: *"How do I create this connection between 2 classes?"*  It is best to keep to one question per ..question.  I voted to close the first question, but have supplied an answer to the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a Point in your circle class

```
public class Circle()
{
    private Point center;
    private int radius;

    public Circle(Point center, int radius)
    {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    Public Circle(int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        this(new Point(x, y), radius);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Whoa, that was fast.

Okay, assuming I'm defining my private variables as Point A and int r in the beginning, then it would be this.center = A, right? Just wanna be sure that I'm clear about which variable corresponds to which variable ...

Comment: If you have private variable `Point A` and `int r` then the first constructor as I've written it would be `this.A = center; this.r = radius;` - `this` is only required to make it clear you are intending to "use" the instance variables rather than the method parameters. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create this connection between 2 classes?

One might keep a reference to the other, or be passed the other at relevant times (e.g. when drawing).

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this

```
class Circle
{
    Point point;
    Double radius;
    Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
    {
       point = new Point(x,y);
       this.radius = radius;
    }
 }
```

This way your Circle class contains a Point, which handles the co-ordinates, but has additional information (radius)